# Apps Script: Loop Function to Submit Active Google Sheet entries to running log sheet in same file?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to loop through the following script to set values in my target sheet for all entries below cell a21 in the 'order entry template' i've created in the 'PO Template' sheet.

```
function submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var PONo = activeSheet.getRange("N3").getValue();
  var PODate = activeSheet.getRange("N4").getValue();
  var SKU = activeSheet.getRange("a22").getValue();
  var SKUDesc = activeSheet.getRange("d22").getValue();
  var SKUQty = activeSheet.getRange("k22").getValue();
  var UtCost = activeSheet.getRange("m22").getValue();
  var ExtCost = activeSheet.getRange("p22").getValue();
  var target = "POHistory";
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(target);
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(PONo);
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue(PODate);  
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 3).setValue(SKU);
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 4).setValue(SKUDesc);
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 5).setValue(SKUQty)
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 6).setValue(UtCost);
   targetSheet.getRange(2, 7).setValue(ExtCost);  
}
```

Comment: Is your script working? Are you trying to improve it (e.g. using setValues() instead of setValue(), which is much slower), or you posted the sample code just for one row and you want to iterate over every single row after the 21st?

Comment: I am trying to iterate over every single row that (until blank) after the 21st.  New to loops, unfortunately.  Thanks k4k

Comment: Let's see...   `var PONo = activeSheet.getRange("N3").getValue();`
  `var PODate = activeSheet.getRange("N4").getValue();`, do they change in loop? All the other ranges are in row 22: during the loop the row will be increased by 1 until the last populated row, what about N3 and N4?

Comment: Great question - sorry for not including mention of that.  Only those variables that start in row 22 (as shown in the code) are subject to change as we loop through those entries starting in row 22.   Sorry, again.

Comment: No worries! Now I get it. I'll post some code for you to test

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are! Need to run now, I'll add comments later:

```
function submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var tplSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  // POTemplate range size
  // I prefer not having ranges in A1 notation when I'm going to iterate
  var tplFRow = 22, tplLRow = tplSheet.getLastRow();
  var tplRowsNum = tplLRow - tplFRow + 1;
  var tplFCol = 1, tplLCol = 16;
  var tplColsNum = tplLCol - tplFCol + 1;
  // Get all data at once: less getValue() calls, much faster
  var rangeData = tplSheet.getRange(22, 1, tplRowsNum, tplColsNum).getValues();
  // Column indexes to filter (A, D, K, M, P)
  var colIndexes = [0, 3, 10, 12, 15];
  var fData = filterByIndexes(rangeData, colIndexes);
  var target = "POHistory";
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(target);
  // Set size of destination range in POHistory sheet
  var tgtRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var tgtRowsNum = fData.length - tgtRow + 1;
  var tgtCol = 1;
  var tgtColsNum = fData[0].length - 1 + 1;
  // Set all values at once
  targetSheet.getRange(tgtRow, tgtCol, tgtRowsNum, tgtColsNum).setValues(fData);
}
// Function to extract only the columns you need
function filterByIndexes(twoDArr, indexArr) {
  var fData = [];
  // Transpose Array to get only the column needed
  twoDArr = twoDArr.transpose();
  for(var i=0; i<indexArr.length; i++) {
    fData.push(twoDArr[indexArr[i]]);
  }
  // Transpose result Array
  return fData.transpose();
}

// Prototype function to transpose a 2D Array
Array.prototype.transpose = function() {
  var a = this,
      w = a.length ? a.length : 0,
      h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;
  if (h === 0 || w === 0) {return [];}
  var i, j, t = [];
  for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    t[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
      t[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
  }
  return t;
};
```

Comment: Thanks K4K, this should work great!  Running into one small snag, though.  Getting an error that says the following:

Incorrect range height, was 22 but should be 18 (line 76, file "Code")

Comment: I also meant to mention - I am hoping the transposed data includes mention of cell value N3 and N4 for each entry it pulls over.  I apologize for not being fully clear.

Comment: Sorry, I’m sooo busy these days.. I’ll check again and edit the code above. About N3 and N4, we can either insert them into the fData Array or add another .setValues() just for the first two columns.

Comment: Great!  Thanks, in advance.  I will be eagerly awaiting your added help.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I feel like a kid awaiting Christmas morning for your updates, k4k. Very excited to get your answer, when you have some availability.  Have a great weekend, if I don't hear from you...

Comment: Wondering if you might have time to look at this one tonight, K4K?